# HTTP Streaming in .Net

Tags: http, streaming, odata

I want to write a server which clients can consume.

So the code at the client will look like something like below

```
req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateDefault(new Uri(FCookieLocation));
HttpWebResponse resp1 = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
```

I want to then do something like

```
while (true)
{
    byte b = stream.ReadByte();
}
```

Eventually the server will run out of data and the client should know that the response has finished(Not sure ho to do that either.)

The preference would be to have the server be used in conjunction with a CRUD service like WCF Data Service (or just a plain WCF service) as I do not want the client to access  URLs that look to distinct.

Or do I have no choice but to write an independent server that is separate from my CRUD service to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Streaming with WCF? A quick google search resulted in this MSDN article that provides a sample implementation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751463.aspx

Does this not fit your needs?

Comment: Not exactly as I need to do this via HTTP as the other non .Net apps if you need access to this resource and other technologies tend to at least know HTTP